# PHP regex allow dashes in this pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex for image file names validation:

`/^\w*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/`

But the thing is that file name can contain dash `-` character. eg: `564SDD-DSS.png`

How do i include dash into this statement? Do i need to escape it?

`/^\w\-*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/`

or

`/^[\w\-]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/` ?

I got a bit lost.

Comment: *offtopic* Respect my authoritah!

Comment: Had you actually tried *running* these expressions you'd have found that the last one does exactly what you're asking and saved yourself a trip to SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `[\w-]` will do.  Instead of the `*` you probably want `+` as I'm sure the basename is at least one character long.  All together:

```
/^[\w-]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i
```

Note that this does allow a filename that is just `-.jpg`

Comment: You might want to add the `i` modifier. thisway you can also includes capital letters in the file-extension

Comment: Thank you! Could you please tell me what does  `?` do in here: `jpe?g`, it checks one character befor `?`

Comment: @rinchik it makes the `e` optional so it allows either `jpeg` or `jpg`.  You can of course use what you had before too.

Comment: Not that it matters, but \w is already case insensitive.  The i modifier would help if you were using [a-z], or any other combination of statically typed letters.  Just a fun fact.

Comment: @Suamere yes, but `i` makes the extension case insensitive too

Comment: Lol, look at me being all narrow sighted.  I was just thinking of the \w.  I obviously need sleep.  /slap